# what is the difference between hook_insert and hook_node_insert

Tags: 7

what is the difference between hook_insert and hook_node_insert? How could I use hook_insert in place of hook_node_insert or vice versa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is stated in the [hook_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_insert/7) documentation:

> This hook is invoked only on the module that defines the node's
>   content type (use hook_node_insert() to act on all node insertions).

This hook is only fired on the module that defines its own content type for nodes of that content type, so you only should use it in this case for your own content types.